# Finding the max value for a hierarchy level over another level

Tags: pandas

Let's say I have a DataFrame like this:

```
l1  1      2   
l2  1  13  99  89
0   1  2   2   1
```

and for each value of `l1`, I want to find the corresponding max value amongst the `l2` values under that `l1` value. Is there an easy way to do this using groupby?

so in the above example it would be `1->2` and `2->99`

My current solution is along the lines of:

```
grouped = swapped.groupby(level="l1",axis=1)
maxes = []
for n,g in grouped:
   maxes.append((n, max([x[1] for x in g.columns]))) # we take max over level l2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [33]: df = DataFrame([[1,2,2,1]],
         columns=MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1,1),(1,13),(2,99),(2,89)],names=['l1','l2']))

In [34]: df
Out[34]: 
l1   1       2    
l2  1   13  99  89
0    1   2   2   1

In [35]: df.T.reset_index().groupby('l1').max()
Out[35]: 
    l2  0
l1       
1   13  2
2   99  2
```