# Indexing DataFrame by Argmax of Column over Another Column

Tags: python, pandas

This is slightly related to: [Finding the max value for a hierarchy level over another level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474840/finding-the-max-value-for-a-hierarchy-level-over-another-level)

In this question I am asking how to find the most recent observation over a given value. For example, let's say I have a series of observations at different dates for different cities. I would to take the most recent observation for each city. In the example below the observations are the tuple of values v1, v2, v3

Let's say I have a data frame like this:

```
city  obs_dt  v1  v2  v3 
LA    1/1/12  13  99  89
LA    1/1/13  2   2   1
NY    1/1/11  4   2   1
NY    1/1/13  2   22  1
NY    1/9/13  3   2   1
Bo    1/9/13  2   23  1
```

I would want a result that looks like:

```
city  obs_dt  v1  v2  v3 
LA    1/1/13  2   2   1
NY    1/9/13  3   2   1
Bo    1/9/13  2   23  1
```

Currently I am solving this problem like this:

```
most_recent_dates = raw_data.groupby(["city"]).max()
most_recent_dates_idxed = most_recent_dates.set_index("obs_dt", append=True)
raw_data_idxed = raw_data.set_index(["city", "obs_dt"])
newest_raw = raw_data_idxed.join(most_recent_dates_idxed, how="inner", rsuffix="_max")
newest = newest_raw.drop(labels=(x for x in newest_raw if x.endswith("_max")), axis=1)
```

which seems like a lot of code to accomplish what I want.

Formerly what I am looking for is to index by the argmax of a column over another column.

The obs_dt column is a datetime column. I have made it look like a string just for the purpose of the question.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't quite answer the indexing-using-argmax question, but is how I handle this problem in practice.

First I'd turn your `obs_dt` column into a `datetime` column so you don't get into trouble taking the maximum of a string due to lexicographic comparisons.  If you're reading this in from a file it'd probably be better to parse the dates using one of the `read_csv` options so they're right from the beginning.  (I'm not sure whether you're DD/MM/YY or MM/DD/YY; be careful.)

Then I'd `sort` by the date, `groupby` on the city, and take the `last`.  It's a little less elegant, because you really only need the maximum, not to sort the whole list, but unless the data is really, really big I find it's usually a good idea to sort it at the start anyway..

Example:

```
>>> df
  city  obs_dt  v1  v2  v3
0   LA  1/1/12  13  99  89
1   LA  1/1/13   2   2   1
2   NY  1/1/11   4   2   1
3   NY  1/1/13   2  22   1
4   NY  1/9/13   3   2   1
5   Bo  1/9/13   2  23   1
>>> df["obs_dt"] = pd.to_datetime(df["obs_dt"])
>>> df.sort("obs_dt").groupby("city", as_index=False).last()
  city              obs_dt  v1  v2  v3
0   Bo 2013-01-09 00:00:00   2  23   1
1   LA 2013-01-01 00:00:00   2   2   1
2   NY 2013-01-09 00:00:00   3   2   1
```

(If the city order is important, we could preserve that too, if needed.)